# html2canvas crashes Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, canvas, windows-8, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10

I ran several tests on internet explorer 10 with the html2canvas script http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
It seems that the script makes Internet Explorer 10 Consumer Preview crash without any information why.
Just give http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/tests/z-index2.html a few refreshes and IE10 will crash. I suspect that the bug lies on the `clientRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();` on line 53 of the script http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/js/html2canvas.js
It seems that Internet Explorer crashes exactly on that line.
I would greatly appreciate any help in fixing this crash.

Comment: make sure the document mode is not on Quirks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demos appear to be working fine for me in Internet Explorer 10.0.8400.0 (Release Preview). Keep in mind that IE10 is not yet fully completed, and therefore your copy of the Consumer Preview would have been experiencing some issues - this is just a guess though, since any number of things could have caused the crash.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it has been fixed on Release Preview :)